# Seek a considerably good performance deep learning architecture to run style transfer algorithm

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe, torch

Our boss found the idea of the paper "A Neural Algorithm of Artistic Style" amazing and think it should attract some of his customers. He decided to set up a server provide the service of style transfer for them.

There are several deep learning architectures with implementations of this idea such as TensorFlow, Torch, caffe, etc. If aims to achieve the best performance, which implementation of these architectures runs fastest? If we configure the algorithm with a considerably good CUDA device such as GeForce GTX 1090 or better, is it possible to finish the task of a VGG model in several seconds? If wish to apply the state of art of the idea to the aforementioned deep learning architectures, are they all applicable?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean here what's wrong with my post? It is specific and not poorly grammatical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking out some benchmarks: https://github.com/soumith/convnet-benchmarks I'd say that `Nervana` and `Torch` are the best frameworks.

If instead of time, we have a look at open source contributions and paper implementations I think `torch` is the winner.

You can easily find neural-style algorithm implementations in Torch: [Neural-Style](https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style) and [Fast Neural-Style](https://github.com/jcjohnson/fast-neural-style)

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how much fast speed if torch + fast neural style + GeForce GTX 1090 (or something like it or better than it) can achieve for a VGG model?

Comment: I do not know sorry :( Since it is a very specific question i bet the best is to set up torch + cuda and cudnn, fast neural -style code and try it by yourself. That shouldn't take you more than 30-40 min.